# some lines of javascript/node.js code is not executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

`app.get` is not executed, why? I have also tried to put `app.listen(3000)`. I want to get the parameter I passed by first web page. This code wants to get parameters passed by another web page and then builds mysql query and table. Thanks in advance guys. If you need some extra details ask me!

```
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'andrea',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'scuola',
  charset: 'utf8'
});

//html string that will be send to browser
var reo ='<html><head><title>Voti</title></head><body><h1>Voti</h1>{${table}}</body></html>';

var express = require("express");
var app = express();

let idAlunno=0;

var sqlAlunni ='SELECT * FROM registro_voti WHERE id_alunno =';

idAlunno = '"'+idAlunno+'"';
//console.log("idAlunno="+idAlunno);

function setResHtml(sql, cb){
      pool.getConnection((err, con)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        app.get('*',function(request, response){
            console.log("app.get()");
            console.log("request.idAlunno="+request.idAlunno);
            idAlunno = request.idAlunno;
        });

        con.query(sql+con.escape(idAlunno), (err, res, cols)=>{
          if(err) throw err;

          var rows = ''; //to store html rows

          //create html table with data from res.
          for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
              rows += `<tr><td style="cursor:pointer">${res[i].voto}</td></tr>`;
          }

          var table = `<table border="1" id="table1"><tr><th>Voto</th></tr>${rows}</table>`;

          con.release();       

          return cb(table);
        });
      });
    }

//create the server for browser access
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
  setResHtml(sqlAlunni, resql=>{
    reo = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(reo, 'utf-8');
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8081);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give `app.listen(8081)` instead of `http.createServer(`. Please refer https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: What I do with code that write reo? res.write(reo, 'utf-8');res.end(); how to replace it?

Comment: You should move the `app.get('*'` outside the `setResHtml` function and modify code to call `setResHtml` inside `app.get('*'`. Also use `app.listen` as i mentioned earlier. It is possible to set header using `res.set`. please refer [https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set)